# How to make a view in mySQL (phpmyAdmin) that queries table for specific date range?

Tags: mysql, sql

Essentially I want to create a view in mySQL (phpmyAdmin) that queries a table called Equipment for a date range >=2018-12-1.

This is currently what I have, it is what is wrong with my syntax?

```
CREATE VIEW "Equipment_Date" AS SELECT * FROM "Equipment" 
WHERE "Ship_Del_Date" >= 2018-12-1;
```

Comment: Al those double quotes should be backticks and the date should be in single quotes '2018-12-01' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Below query should work provided **Ship_Del_Date** column has datatype as DATETIME.

```
CREATE VIEW Equipment_Date AS SELECT * FROM Equipment
WHERE Ship_Del_Date >= '2018-12-1';
```

Use backticks instead of single quotes to enclose the table,column names only when the names are from [mysql reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-in-current-series).

Answer (score 0):

Use these to specify databases, tables and columns: `

And not these: "

Or simply just don't use any of these, if not necessary.

Then your SQL query will probably look like this:
`CREATE VIEW Equipment_Date AS SELECT * FROM Equipment WHERE Ship_Del_Date >= 2018-12-1;`

Comment: Worked for me using PHPmyAdmin